Stop system interrupts on app
I am using Linux on a microcontroller with 2 A72 cores, running my app on that, I am trying to measure runtime of a function in app using system call:
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID , &tv);

before and after the function, and calculate the CPU time function used, I do this for thousands of times to profile this function over long run of input data, it happens  that I get very large runtime readings randomly in each run(sometimes not, but the overall curve of data is same and consistent), my explanation that this is system interrupts corrupts my runtime measuring, what do you think ?how to disable it?
I tried to give my app highest priority but still have the issue

you might need to discuss what a microcontroller is. Someething with 2 A72 cores running Linux doesn't sound like it's a microcontroller to me :) These are very much hallmarks of you dealing with a classical application processor CPU, with separate RAM and the need for a complex operating system to set up the hardware :)


I get very large runtime readings randomly

Yes, and that's to be expected; you're asking a pretty imprecise clock, which is dependent on the kernel scheduling's time allocation book keeping.

my explanation that this is system interrupts corrupts my runtime measuring,

no, because interrupts do typically not count into the book keeping of a process runtime
First of all, you need to be sure your application doesn't have multiple threads – because time spent in a different  thread than the one executing your function under test would still count towards its time.
Also, what you do is simply not a good way to measure execution time of a function: as you notice, this is a system call, and these by definition involve a context switch with unspecified timing. So, pretty bad to actually measure time in a fine-grained manner.
So, disabling interrupts a) can't work, your system needs to continue to work and b) seems like not related to your problem.
Instead, use better methods to benchmark your function. If you install bpftrace, you'll find it comes with a bunch of example scripts (typically in /user/share/bpftrace/tools), especially gethostlatency.bt. You can just replace all libc:getaddrinfo (and libc:gethostbyname and libc:gethostbyname2) with the name of your library or executable, and the name of your function of interest.
That way, all the measuring of time happens in the kernel, at low latency.
